# If N $\lhd$ of G (finite group) . Show that all complements for N in G are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Definition: A subgroup $H < G$ is said to be a complement for $N$ in $G$ if $NH = G$ and $N\cap H = \{e\}$.

Let $N \lhd G$ (normal subgroup) of a finite group $G$.

Show that all complements for $N$ in $G$ are isomorphic.

My attempt: I have to choose two arbitrary complements of N in G and prove that they are isomorphic.

Let $H_1$ be a complement of $N$ in $G$ if $NH_1 = G$ and $N\cap H_1 = \{e\}$.
Also, let $H_2$ be another complement of $N$ in $G$ if $NH_2 = G$ and $N\cap H_2 = \{e\}$.

I have to show that $H_1$ is isomorphic to $H_2$, since both are arbitrary complement it will follows that all the complements of $N$ in $G$ are isomorphic.

I know that if $N \lhd G$, then $\exists \phi \in\operatorname{Hom} (G)$ such that $\phi$ is an homeomorphism on $G$ for which $N = \ker\phi$.

But I need an isomorphism, how can I modify or justified that the homeomorphism is an isomorphism with the complement property ?

Answer (score 3):

**hint:** Consider the composition of inclusion and projection $H \to G \to G/N$, and show that this is an isomorphism.

*for injectivity:* What is the kernel?

*for surjectivity:* an element of $G/N$ is of the form $aN$ with $a \in G$. Why can we write $hn=a$ with $h \in H$ an $n \in N$?

Comment: This is for one of the complements to be isomorphic to the quotient group. I will need to construct two of these function and compose with the the inverse of the other complement isomorphism then use the fact that the composition of isomorphic functions are isomorphic ?

Comment: Also this isomorphism is given for free by applying the second theorem is isomorphism right ?

Comment: So, if all the complements are isomorphic to one thing, they are all isomorphic. Isomorphism classes are equivalence classes, so transitive. But yeah, you could do it that way as well.